# Using Google API get Latitude, Longitude from places and get specific country for the same(using PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

Using Google API get Latitude, Longitude from places and get specific country for the same. How can I do it? (using PHP)

```
$formattedAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
//Sending request and receive json data by address

$geocodeFromAddr=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddr.'&sensor=false');
$output = json_decode($geocodeFromAddr);

//Get latitude and longitute from json data

$data['latitude']  = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$data['longitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab it from `formatted_address` property. It contains full address, comma separeted with *country* after last comma. Try with:

```
$formatted_address = $output->results[0]->formatted_address;

$country = trim(end(explode(',',$formatted_address)));
```